# PHP doesnt store Arabic/Persian text correctly in my XAMPP server

Tags: php, android, mysql, arabic, persian

I have a PHP script that gets text as `$name` from my android app and store image with the `$name` as image name in my local XAMPP server in `$path = "uploads/$name.png"` location .

When i type Persian/Arabic data it store them like:

`Ù…Ø§Ø³Øª.png`
`Ù…Ø§ Ø³Øª.png`

but it works like charm in English text :

`carrot.png`

Can any one help me to store the Persian/Arabic correctly as they typed?

Thanks.

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    $image = $_POST['image'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    define('DB_NAME', 'android');
    $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
    $path = "uploads/$name.png";
    $actualpath = "http://192.168.1.107/login1/image_up/$path";
    $sql = "INSERT INTO imgnews (userNews,userMatn) VALUES ('$actualpath','$name')";
    //
    if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
        file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($image));
        echo "Successfully Uploaded";
    }
//mysql_real_escape_string($conn,$name);
    mysqli_close($conn);
}else{
    echo "Error";
}
```

i upload some pictures about my situation :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PU4sA.png)////

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luOky.png)////

Comment: Whats the tables collations say? It's prob set as `latin`, use `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` instead.

Comment: i checked this before , thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have set you db collection to UTF-8 Then
Add this header to your php script
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
your php Script should also support utf-8.

Comment: please make sure your database Character Set is set to utf-8 And column collection to utf8_general_ci

Answer (score 0):

change the collation of database or table to UTF-8_Unicode_ci